# Bijective linear operators on Banach spaces with non-continuous inverse

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, banach-spaces

I am reading a lecture note on functional analysis, and the author claims there exist normed spaces $S$ with linear bijective continuous operators $S\longrightarrow S$ whose inverse is not continuous. In particular, this is claimed to be true about the space $c_{0,0}$ of sequences $(a_{i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $a_{i}\in\mathbb{K}\in\left\{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\right\}$ and $a_{i}=0$ for all but finitely many $i\in\mathbb{N}$, with the topology induced by the maximum norm.

Why is that so? I mean linear operators are continuous if and only if they are bounded, and I am having trouble understanding why a bounded operator can have a non-bounded inverse. Is $c_{0,0}$ even a Banach space?

Comment: It is not a Banach space. That is the whole point. In Banach spaces this cannot happen due to the inverse mapping theorem.

Comment: For a specific example you may consider the map $T:c_{00}\rightarrow c_{00}, (a_n)\mapsto (n^{-1} a_n)$. The inverse is mapping $(a_n)\mapsto (n a_n)$, which is clearly not bounded.

Comment: found it out myself, thank you all for the hints.

Comment: Glad to hear :) maybe you could write down an answer with your insight,. then the next person with the same question gets enlightend as well.

Answer (score 0):

The function $a_i\longrightarrow\frac{1}{i+1}a_i$ does the job. Its inverse is $a_i\longrightarrow({i+1})a_i$. This is clearly unbounded and therefore not continuous.

Comment: You might want to specify the domain (this is the crucial part of this exercise). For example the map is not a bijection for $\ell^2(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R})$.